# Convert a list of dict that has list to one dataframe

Tags: pandas

whats the most efficient way to convert this?

given a list of dict with a list.

```
list_df = [
  {'High':[2,3,4,5,5,3,3,4,5,5],'Low':[0,-3,1,4,1,2,2,3,1,-1],'Name':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']},
  {'High':[35,23,424,5,25,3,223,4,5,255],'Low':[3,3,44,5,2,3,22,2,1,25]},'Name':['B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
]
```

if i do `df = pd.DataFrame(list_df)`, then each row is a list of the values.
the resulting is

```
    Name High Low
0 [A,A,..][2,3,4..][0,-3,1..]
1 [B,B,..][35,23,424..][3,3,44..]
```

What I'd like is:

```
Name High Low
 A   2    0
 A   3   -3
 A   4    1
 A   5    4
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in list_df])
Out[190]: 
   High  Low Name
0     2    0    A
1     3   -3    A
2     4    1    A
3     5    4    A
4     5    1    A
5     3    2    A
6     3    2    A
7     4    3    A
8     5    1    A
9     5   -1    A
0    35    3    B
1    23    3    B
2   424   44    B
3     5    5    B
4    25    2    B
5     3    3    B
6   223   22    B
7     4    2    B
8     5    1    B
9   255   25    B
```